# How to convert text format list into a python list

Tags: python, parsing

I am getting various data types from a config file and adding them to a dictionary.  but I am having a problem with lists.  I want to take a line with text: `alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and convert into a list of integers.  But I am getting

```
['1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5', ',', '6', ',', '7'].
```

How can I fix this?

Here is config.txt:

```
firstname="Joe"
lastname="Bloggs"
employeeId=715
type="ios"
push-token="12345"
time-stamp="Mon, 22 Jul 2013 18:45:58 GMT"
api-version="1" 
phone="1010"
level=7
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Here is my code to parse:

```
mapper = {}

def massage_type(s):
    if s.startswith('"'):
        return s[1:-1]
    elif s.startswith('['):
        return list(s[1:-1])   #in this case get 'mylist': ['1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5', ',', '6', ',', '7']
    elif s.startswith('{'):
        return "object"   #todo
    else:
        return int(s)



doc = open('config.txt')
for line in doc:
    line = line.strip()
    tokens = line.split('=')
    if len(tokens) == 2:
        formatted = massage_type(tokens[1])
        mapper[tokens[0]] = formatted

    #check integer list
    mapper["properlist"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  #this one works

print mapper
```

Here is my printed output:

```
{'time-stamp': 'Mon, 22 Jul 2013 18:45:58 GMT', 'mylist': ['1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5', ',', '6', ',', '7'], 'employeeId': 715, 'firstname': 'Joe', 'level': 7, 'properlist': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'lastname': 'Bloggs', 'phone': '1010', 'push-token': '12345', 'api-version': '1', 'type': 'ios'}
```

Update.

Thanks for the feedback.  I realised that I could also get heterogeneous list so changed list part to:

```
elif s.startswith('['):
    #check element type
    elements = s[1:-1].split(',')
    tmplist = []           #assemble temp list
    for elem in elements:
        if elem.startswith('"'):
            tmplist.append(elem[1:-1])
        else:
            tmplist.append(int(elem))

    return tmplist
```

It only handles strings and integers but is good enough for what I need right now.

Comment: Have you considered using ConfigParser? http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html and Python3: http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/configparser.html
It certainly makes parsing configuration files pretty easy.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` may be what you want, depending on what you want. :-)

Comment: @erewok: I have used "configobj" a lot too: see http://www.decalage.info/en/python/configparser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `return` statement to.

```
return [int(elem) for elem in s[1:-1].split(',')] # Or map(int, s[1:-1].split(','))
```

Comment: you dont need a lambda in the map

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe try `ast.literal_eval`

here is an example:

```
import ast

str1 = '[1,2,3,4,5]'
ast.literal_eval(str1)
```

output will be a list like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

it wont include the commas in the list

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using ConfigParser (Python 3 example below, Python 2 imports `ConfigParser.ConfigParser`, I believe):

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
conf_file = os.path.join(dir_it's_located_in, 'config.txt')
parser.read(conf_file)
```

After that, it's really basic: your whole config file is treated like a dictionary object and all configuration lines are keys in the dictionary:

```
firstname = parser['firstname']
lastname = parser['lastname']
```

You can also set up sections in your configuration like so:

```
[employee info]
email = "something@something.com"
birthday = 10/12/98
```

And you can reference these in the following way:

```
birthday = parser["employee info"]["birthday"]
```

And, as always, there are some great examples in the docs: http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`:

```
elif s.startswith('['):
    return [int(x) for x in s[1:-1].split(',')]
```

This will give you the list without the commas.

Answer (score 0):

ummm

```
elif s.startswith('['):
        return map(int,s[1:-1].split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're converting a string to a list of characters. You want to be doing this:

```
map(int, str[1:-1].split(','))
```

That will give you the list of ints you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using ConfigParser as @erewok mentioned, here's the whole "parser"

```
def parse(content):

    def parseList(content):
        # Recursive strategy
        listed = content.strip("[]").split(",")
        return map(parse, listed)

    def parseString(content):
        return content.strip("\"")

    def parseNumber(content):
        return int(content)

    def parse(content):
        if (content.startswith("\"")):
            return parseString(content)
        elif (content.startswith("[")):
            return parseList(content)
        elif (content.isdigit()):
            return parseNumber(content)

    # Create dictionary with values
    result = {}

    for line in content.splitlines():
        key, value = line.split("=",1)
        result[key] = parse(value)

    return result
```

I'm using a recursive strategy to sub-parse elements within the list you are getting, in case the list comes with numbers and strings mixed